# openssl issuer/subject format differences

Tags: openssl

I get different issuer/subject format for two OpenSSL versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1 and OpenSSL 1.0.2n. Can 1.1.1 version format subject/issuer like 1.0.2n does?

```
$ openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -issuer

# 1.1.1 11 Sep 2018
issuer=C = RU, O = TestOrg, OU = TestOrg Certification Authority, CN = rsa

# 1.0.2n 7 Dec 2017
issuer= /C=RU/O=TestOrg/OU=TestOrg Certification Authority/CN=rsa
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the "-nameopt compat" [option](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/x509.html).
e.g.

> openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -issuer -nameopt compat

From documentation:

> -nameopt option
>
> option which determines how the subject or issuer names are displayed.
>   The option argument can be a single option or multiple options
>   separated by commas. Alternatively the -nameopt switch may be used
>   more than once to set multiple options. See the NAME OPTIONS section
>   for more information.

and

> compat
>
> use the old format. This is equivalent to specifying no name options
>   at all.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that `-nameopt compat` is not so compatible, with the output of 1.0.2 and 1.1.1 being the other's default format, so you can't use `compat` if you don't control your environment. See https://github.com/apel/ssm/issues/167 for an example.

One option is to use `-nameopt oneline`, which is pretty consistent, with just an extra space in 1.0.2:

```
$ openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -issuer -nameopt oneline

# 1.1.1f
issuer=C = RU, O = TestOrg, OU = TestOrg Certification Authority, CN = rsa

# 1.0.2k
issuer= C = RU, O = TestOrg, OU = TestOrg Certification Authority, CN = rsa
```

Overall the output is quite inconsistent between versions and sub-versions, and the manpage seems to have issues as well. It's safest to treat this as not machine-readable, and parse heuristically.